# How can I detect flipping in a time series?

Tags: python, time-series

For a system that operates on different operational modes, I want to reduce the flipping between modes. For this the detection of flipping and the correction is needed.

Let's assume we have a sequence where modes switch frequently:

```
before = [0,0,0,(1,0),1,1,1,2,2,(1,2),1,1,1,(0,1),0]   # parenthesis indicate flipping
```

I would like to kind of swap only at (changing points) to get :

```
after  = [0,0,0,(0,1),1,1,1,2,2,(2,1),1,1,1,(1,0),0]   # parenthesis indicate corrections
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your question is quite interesting. I think your own efforts should be part of the question. I thought at first this question had been suitable answered.

Comment: Are mode changes like `0,1,2` or `0,1,1,2` possible? Or even `0,2`?

Comment: Actually the answer reflects my own solution, as I didn't get external support so far.
My initial question was closed after 3 days.

Comment: @Wups So far it only regarded single steps. With the convolutional approach two steps are easy to add by adding an additional if statement. It's important to ensure there is no ambiguity introduced. This is why my filter values are chosen as `[1,2,5,10]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by developing a small convolution filter for flipping detection.
So far it can detect a single flip (on-off-on or off-on-off)

building the differential signal allows to support different single swaps even between more than 2 operational modes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

before = np.array([0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,0,0])
goal = np.array(  [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])
after  = before.copy()
fltr = np.array([1,2,5,10])        # convolution filter

for i in range(0,len(before)-4):
    dif = np.diff(after)
    conv = (fltr*dif[i:i+4]).sum() # conv-filter applied on diff()
    if abs(conv) == 3:       # 00100 = 00000 or 11011 = 11111
        after[i+2] = after[i+1]  
    if abs(conv) == 7:
        b = after[i+2]       # 00101 = 00011 or 11010 = 11100
        after[i+2] = after[i+3]
        after[i+3] = b

plt.plot(before, linestyle='--',label='before')
plt.plot(goal,   linestyle='-.',label='goal')
plt.plot(after,  linestyle=':', label='after')

plt.legend()
plt.show
```

**Note:** maybe this solution is incomplete and does not cover all possible scenarios. Please recommend more advanced / alternative solutions.

Comment: Can you explain why use a filter, where you could just compare each sample to the next (and previous) one to see a flipping?

Comment: The advantage of using a **convolutional filter** is, it regards not only the current and the previous. As convolution integrates over 5 samples (4 diff's) it looks 2 samples into *future* and into the *past*. If you would implement this with *if statements*, it would get very messy.

Answer (score 3):

There is a 'simpler' way to find flippings of range 1, but doesn't work for consecutive repeated flips

```
before = np.array([0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,0,0])
goal = np.array(  [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])

diff = np.diff(before)          # find 'jumps' with range 1
diff[:-1][(diff == 0)[1:]] = 0  # correct 'right' side of 'jumps'
after = before - np.r_[0,diff]  # correct flipping

plt.plot(before, linestyle='--',label='before')
plt.plot(goal,   linestyle='-.',label='goal')
plt.plot(after,  linestyle=':', label='after')
plt.legend();
```

Output

[image: smothed signal]

Works with bigger steps and negative 'jumps'

```
before = np.array([0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,4,4,1,4,1,1,1,0,1,0,0])
goal = np.array(  [0,0, 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])

diff = np.diff(before)          # find flipping with range 1
diff[:-1][(diff == 0)[1:]] = 0  # correct 'right' side of signal
after = before - np.r_[0,diff]  # correct flipping

plt.plot(before, linestyle='--',label='before')
plt.plot(goal,   linestyle='-.',label='goal')
plt.plot(after,  linestyle=':', label='after')
plt.legend();
```

Output

[image: with bigger steps]

---

### Limits of the solution

- Consecutive repeated flips

```
    before = [0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]
    goal   = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

[image: wrong result]

Comment: This is a very good point. When a system is constantly flipping you can't assign it to one or the other state. But you can still use the convolution to detect it [0,1,0,1,0] would convolve to -6 and `[1,0,1,0,1] would give 6 based on my answer below. –